# RP2040 1.28 WAVESHARE TOUCH LCD

Tags: lcd

I'm using this library successfully for almost a year now. I used GC9A01 & GC9A01 with touch and it is great. Lately I purchased a RP2040 1.28 WAVESHARE TOUCH LCD which I thought it would be easy to manage as it uses the same hardware , but ... no luck.
I tried the clock example and used the Dev-Device-Declaration#waveshare-rp2040-lcd-128 but nothing comes on the screen.
Does anybody had any experience with this module? Any help would be appreciated.
Lucas

Comment: Your question seems to be *"Does anybody had any experience with this module?"* How will an answer to that help you?

Comment: Very simple,This is a way to start a good conversation if the answer is positive.

Comment: That is the difficulty. This is a Q&A site. There are places that can work like that. The Arduino Forum, Reddit, Discord, etc. *Here* the idea is to ask questions that are answerable with little to no back-and-forth discussion. I doubt you want people post answers that say "yes" or "probably." If you edit your post to contain a single clear answerable question you're more likely to have luck getting a useful answer. If you re-post this on the Forum or wherever, still you're better off providing the next step on the assumption that someone is familiar with it. Just means one less round trip.

Comment: Got it, I understand your spirit. Nevertheless there should be space (depend on the question) for generic questions because this improves knowledge, this is my point of view of course and I do not expect to change the rules. Thanks for been polite and honest.